# Ensure Linux (suse) Programs Level across multiple servers with cksum

Tags: linux, unix, checksum, suse, md5sum

We have a GOLD image new servers are imaged from new ones are created.

Over time some of these have become out of sync due to poorly managed rollouts.

I would like to scan all of these servers bin folders and compare to what the GOLD image has into a output file.   (IE: if different flag one way.  If same say Same, if missing say Missing, if there but not on gold. Addition?)

1. I was going to accomplish via like below.

on the Gold Image run following example.

```
for x in `ls /bin/`
do
cksum $x >> /data/OnGold.lst
done
```

1. Distribute this file to all of servers along with another script that will execute the same thing with a different log name.
2. after the script executes another script will Diff the two files and report on the differences based off of the cksum or if files are missing or in addition to the OnGold.lst

(This is what I could use some advice on the best way to achieve this?   Or if anyone knows of some open source tools that could accomplish the same thing?   assuming.  pretty sure diff would do the trick as it will advise if items were misssing or in addition but I dont know how to format this in a report format.)

Any help would be greatly appreciated?

Comment: It's more than likely that your package manager has an option to verify all the files owned by specific packages. I would only use checksumming on files not included in packages, and then I would recommend using a stronger checksum than `cksum`'s simple CRC - perhaps `md5sum` or `sha1sum`...

Comment: Hi twalberg,  all of the programs in question would have not all used a particular package manager and most are custom shell scripts and ESQL c programs.   I'm open to using md5sum/etc. i just could use some assistance/guidance/example on the reporting aspect from results of diff/etc.